# How to fix admin url redirection in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, redirect

One of my client website has been hacked, So we are unable to login wordpress using old username and password, Then I have inserted duplicate admin username and password using SQL, But whenever I am trying to login like `www.example.com/wp-admin` it will automatically redirected to `www.example.com/otherfolder/wp-admin` and its through 404 error. There is no `otherfolder` exists in server.

I was updated with latest wordpress then no luck, I looked all the tables like options in phpmyadmin, even htaccess there is no redirection for admin url.

I guess there they might be installed some plugin to do this. Currently I am unable to login wordpress how can I fix this and login into wordpress??

I have cpanel access!

Thanks your time.

Comment: Please check the database, the table wp_options. Maybe the URL was changed. 
Also, check the htaccess file... Or, just restore a backup when its possible.

Comment: I have checked database and wp_options and htaccess nothing was changed, they dont have any backups.

Comment: Maybe rename your plugin folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you think there is some plugin which is doing that then go to your wp-content directory and change the name of `"plugins"` folder as `"old__plugins"`. This will automatically `deactivate` all your `active plugins`. If this still won't resolve your issue try searching your functions.php file for the redirection. 
If you still don't find anything the then he downloads all your WordPress files and export SQL database and tries to search `"otherfolder"` in them using any text editor so you will get an idea where exactly that `redirection took place`.

Comment: It perfectly make sense.